# How to run background tasks in expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am working on app where I have some requirement to run method in background if user open an another app like google map etc . I really tried hard but didn't find any solution to resolve my problem . Could someone please help me in example snip or video tutorial

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Expo take a look at the expo-background-fetch module which allows for specific code execution in the background:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/

Since you mentioned Google Maps here's a video detailing background location in Expo: https://youtu.be/2NUUN0dX4kE

In general background code execution is weakly supported by Expo...